# How to put table in 3rd normal form for all days in the week

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am kind of new in the databases, and I was reading documentation and watching videos of how to put my sql table in **3rd Normal Form**, I was trying to fix it by drawing solution, but I couldn't figure the real way of doing it. this is my table:

```
1. ID
2. Username
3. Password 
4. Sunday
5. Monday
6. Tuesday
7. Wednesday
8. Thursday
9. Friday
10. Saturday
11. checkbox checked
```

My question is do I need separate tables for all days, something like `first row: username`, `second row day`, `third row checkbox checked`. if yes, how would you suggest doing that?

I am using `phpmyadmin` to work with the database, phpmyadmin provides help with normalization but it's really confusing.

Anyone has an idea how to solve this problem? I hope this question is for here, if not I will kindly remove it and post somewhere else.

Comment: It seems that your desing may be normalized already, depending on the logic of the data you are storing. As it is, the model says that for each entry you will have 7 datum, one for each day of the week, and also a "check". Is that correct? Now, if you will have a super dynamic set of columns, then you should separate them in different tables.

Comment: What my idea is to know if for example I have HTML like input[checkbox] and when checkbox.checked = true, I want to store that for every entry the user will do plus if they checked the or not and store it but I don't think with one checkbox checked field will fix this, what is your opinion on this?